# findViewById to change background color Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am having some issues trying to make slight modifications to the tutorial from the android website.  I had no issues following the tutorial but when trying to make some slight modifications to further acquaint myself with the constraints, view, layouts, etc., I find myself at a wall.

So far I have almost the exact same work as the tutorial except for trying to send a color to a new activity that changes the background color.

My issue so far is finding the ID to target said window.  With the original tutorial the "R.id.textView" locates a component of the constraints tree, but, having a background color already, I assumed that I could just use the windows/constraint ID to change the color.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_color);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String hexValue = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(parseColor("#" + hexValue));
    }
```

So far I have gone through the docs a fair amount, but they are vast and detailed, so I may be looking for the wrong search terms.

Any help appreciated!  Thank you!

=============================================================

Updated MainActivity code..

```
package com.example.color;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.graphics.Color.parseColor;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeColor(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String hexValue = editText.getText().toString();
        ConstraintLayout conlay = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen);
        conlay.setBackgroundColor(parseColor("#" + hexValue));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is starting to work, but I decided to delete the second activity because it wasn't responding well. Now I have the color changing but it doesn't change the background color of the main screen, and/or it doesn't persist.  But the color does change now!  So thank you for what I have so far!

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: Added activity_main.xml  -- ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the ID of your layout, look for the below line in your xml.

```
android:id="@+id/your_layout_id"
```

Then, you can change the background color of a layout like below.

```
//In your example your_layout_id = screen
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Also, I can see that your layout is a constraint layout and not a relative layout.

So your code to change the background should be like below.

```
ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I modified the code and have a color change working now, I deleted the second activity to streamline this process and help me understand it better.  For now I am trying to have  a button that reads from the EditText box and changes the background color to whatever hex value is passed.  The color changes, but does not persist.

Comment: What do you mean by does not persist? @WhiskeyFace

Comment: When I hit the button to change the color with say "999999" the color changes to a gray background, but the screen refreshes quickly back to the white background with and empty textbox that shows the hint again ("Enter Hex Value").

Comment: I was thinking that I might be able to add the second activity again so that when I hit the button it changes the background color of the second activity screen, so that I can hit the "up" button to go back, but I would prefer to get the action to work on the main screen which was my initial desire.

Comment: That is because you are starting the activity again after changing the background color. Just comment this line startActivity(intent); and it should be fine.
You need startActivity if you are navigating from one activity to another. @WhiskeyFace

Comment: Awesome @Aparna!  Thank you.  That works perfectly now.

Comment: @WhiskeyFace You're welcome. Please upvote the answer if you found it helpful so that it'll benefit others. :)

Comment: I have too little reputation for the time being!  I did try and upvote.  I will as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the new color, save the button with the new color in your folder with custom buttons, and when changing Acitivity, just change bottom background ID in your new activity function

But I believe the mistake is that you save the hex value as a string...

Comment: parseColor() takes a hex string as the parameter and returns an int for the set color function.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)